# Javascript source file unreadable when looking on chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm current new to a project and I've realized that the javascript files that get edited in an IDE aren't readable in chrome. For example. the following is a code snippet that I have in Intellij.

[image]

This is in a file called MNV.js, however opening up the mnv.js file on chrome devtools shows this.

[image]
[image]

Is there something wrong with the configuration of chrome devtools or is this just how the program is supposed to work? Thanks!

EDIT
This project is also using VUE, so this is the vue configuration.

[image]

Comment: Try {} button that is under the line numbers.

Comment: What tool do you use to concat your files? I see your source files set as strings with eval. That’s not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack sometimes bundles code together in this format for debugging purposes, making the source code difficult to read. You can disable the parsing of the code as a string and the `eval` shenanegans by turning off devtool processing of the modules.

In your webpack config, add:

```
devtool: 'none'
```

Comment: Hey, this seems really close to the answer I need, this project is using VUE so do you know how to craft it for that case? I updated my question with a picture of the current VUE setup.

Comment: Random guess: add the line `config.devtool = 'none'`, try that?